# How do I export data structures from Haskell via FFI?

Tags: haskell, ffi

I am trying to make a Haskell library, which is meant to be called from other languages, notably C.

For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP                         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface    #-}

module Example where

import Foreign.C.String as CString

data Person = Person { firstName :: CString  
                      , lastName :: CString }

foreign export ccall entrypoint :: IO (Person)

entrypoint :: IO (Person)
entrypoint = do
    first <- newCString "John"
    last <- newCString "Doe"
    return (Person {firstName = first, lastName = last})
```

When I try to compile this:

```
$ hsc2hs x.hsc && ghc x.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Example          ( x.hs, x.o )

x.hsc:11:1:
    Unacceptable result type in foreign declaration:
      ‘Person’ cannot be marshalled in a foreign call
    When checking declaration:
      foreign export ccall "entrypoint" entrypoint :: IO (Person)
```

How do I do this, and how do I do this with the least boilerplate possible?

I'd also like to see the C structs autogenerated, something along the lines of:

```
struct Person {
   char *firstName;
   char *lastName;
};
```

Maybe I am asking too much from the language & tools, but in that case, I'd really like to know what the (best) options are.

Thank You!

Comment: You define it a `Foreign.Storable.Storable` instance.

Comment: Yes, I could do something like that, but it's very manual, lot of work, not too good for a sensible workflow.

Comment: Generally to do this right you would use hsc2hs, c2hs, etc.
For newtypes that wrap `Storable`s, use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.
Some packages will generate it for you based on Generics. Try querying [storable](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=storable) on Hackage; I've never tried them. Hmm and maybe you could also look up a preprocessor, I've never tried to.
You can also simply write boilerplate but generally, and use it in all your instances.
To be honest, I've instantiated Storable on ADTs just yesterday and I also used hsc2hs, still, it really is pretty horrifying.